# RunTime Error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set - Use of Public Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project that consolidates information from a number of workbooks. While the first version of the application used `Select` and `Activate` extensively, from the information I have seen on this site, the use of these methods should be avoided where possible. As such, I am currently re-vamping the code to eliminate these where possible.

The workbook I am using has a reference sheet which is VeryHidden. In order to reference this sheet, I have made a number of public declarations at the start of the first module; one of which is

```
Public refsheet as Worksheet
```

Please note that this Module may not be used after the workbook has been opened.

**QUESTION 1**: Does this cause an issue if I have my public variables defined in this module when not used? If it does cause an issue, where should these public variables be defined?

In the `Workbook_Open()` event, I have the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set refsheet = Sheets("References")
Set corang = Sheets("Consolidation").Range("L2:AI2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
refsheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

**QUESTION 2**: If I set refsheet in the Workbook_Open() sub, will it be available for use in all other modules given that it has been defined as a public variable?

When I run the code for the first time after using, the first use of refsheet is fine and then anytime refsheet is used after that, I am receiving a Runtime Error 91; Object Variable or With block variable not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is: drop that public variable - Workbook_Open shenanigan entirely. Why do you need this `refsheet` variable at all? You probably don't. Public variables are not *always* a bad idea; they just *usually* are a bad idea.

Just refer to the sheet by its `Name`, or by its `CodeName`. Example:

```
Worksheets("References").Range("A1").Value = "Hello world!" ' Name is "References"
shtReferences.Range("A2").Value = "Hello world!" ' CodeName is shtReferences
```

The second one assumes that you changed the sheet's CodeName to `shtReferences` in the Properties window, top line `(Name)`, as in the example below. This is my favourite way of referencing sheets, because it guards against cases where the user changes the `Name` of the sheet in the sheet tab.

Beware: `(Name)` represents `CodeName`, and this is different from `Name` without parentheses! A bit confusing, I know.

[image]

Note that the `CodeName` of sheets are, by default, `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, ... Adding to the confusion is the fact that the `Name` of sheets are also `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. by default. But `Name` and `CodeName`/`(Name)` are not linked and can be changed independently.

```
MsgBox shtReferences.Name ' returns "References"
MsgBox shtReferences.CodeName ' returns "shtReferences"
```

Comment: Jean-Francois, a very big thank you!!! Being something of a novice to this, referencing objects is still something of a mystery and trying to find a clear explanation is not always straight forward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think something else is going on.  I put this in the workbook code area:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set MySheet = Sheets("xxx")
    MySheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

and I put this in a standard module:

```
Public MySheet As Worksheet

Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox MySheet.Name
End Sub
```

After I re-open the file, I get the expected result by running *MAIN.*

Try this in a new workbook to see if you replicate what I am seeing.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly GS. I am not sure what was going on by Jean-Francois's approach is working a dream.