# How to write a VBA function to sum an infinite range

Tags: vba, excel, sum, range

I need to write a VBA function that will select all values from my range and then display the sum of the range into cell D7. This is all I have thus far. It can not be a Worksheet Function.

```
Sub Statistics()

'count number of cell in Range
Dim count As Long
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
Range("a1").Select
count = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

'output count of cells in Range
Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.Value = count

'This is where I need to write the sum function and output it to D7



End Sub
```

Comment: What is your range that you are summing? As in what column?

Comment: Try `Application.Sum(Range("A:A"))`.

Answer (score 3):

Why write a Sum function when there's one there already?

```
Range("D6").Value = count
Range("D7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1").Resize(count)))
```

Note that you can obtain the same result by calling the same built-in function via the `Application` object instead of the `WorksheetFunction` object:

```
Range("D7").Value = Application.Sum(Range("A1").Resize(count)))
```

It's the exact same `Sum` function. The only difference is how errors are handled:

- With `WorksheetFunction`, errors are treated as VBA errors, trappable using the `On Error` syntax.
- With `Application`, they return an Excel error code wrapped in a Variant. You can use `IsError` to see if the returned variable is an Error type variant.

[More details here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CallingWorksheetFunctionsInVBA.aspx).

If you absolutely must reinvent the wheel, here's how you can calculate the sum explicitly:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sumTotal As Double
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A1").Resize(count)
For i = 1 To count
    sumTotal = sumTotal + arr(i, 1)
Next i
'sumTotal now contains the sum
```

Comment: Some of his other syntax is wrong like `Sheet1.Range` should be `Sheets("Sheet1").Range` and he uses `End Function` instead of `End Sub`

Comment: This works, but it uses a Worksheet Function. It was specified that a Worksheet Function could not be used.

Comment: @Chrismas007: `Sheet1.Range(...)` is in fact perfectly correct syntax. `Sheet1.` uses the sheet's codename while `Sheets("Sheet1")` uses the sheet's `Name` property. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24183859/119775) for details.

Comment: @Winfred: Sure, you speficied that "a worksheet function" couldn't be used but what that meant wasn't clear to me. I thought you meant, can't write a function in the cell of a worksheet, not that you couldn't use the `WorksheetFunction` object in VBA. Why would you have this restriction?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You are assuming the "code name" is not altered in that case.  Might as well define it for future use.  Yes both would work in this circumstance, but defining by name will eliminate any issues with the code for others who might use this answer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Statistics()

'count number of cell in Range

Dim count As Long
count = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

'output count of cells in Range
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Value = count

'Assumes you are looking to sum all values in column A.
'IF NOT change the two values of "A" below and the one above in Rows.Count
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D7").Value = Application.Sum(Range("A1:A" & count))

End Sub 'This started as a sub so has to end as sub.
```